# Debugging WCF Exception causes CommunicationException

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, debugging

I am introduction the use of FaultException in to our WCF services.

To test this is I created the following function on the server:

```
public void ThrowException()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("This is a test exception");
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException<ApplicationException>(ex, "Test reason");

        }
    }
```

Skipping ahead a step. If I run through this it works fine.

However if I use the debugger (VS2008), and allow the code to break in the catch block (by enabling break on exception, or by stepping in to it), my client generates a CommunicationException.

Investigating this I found this forum post: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/d1ae669f-9a62-4628-86c1-c15ff4068843/

Question: Why am I seeing this behaviour, only when debugging  (I assume others are not)? AND how can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Just to be clear, my code does not look at Exception.Data, I ensured it was not in the watch window, and also closed the Watch, Auto and Locals windows.

Comment: i had the same issue, can't remember how i solved it as i ditched WCF due to limitations, but i think it had something to do w/ the configuration of the service in web.config. my suggestion is open fiddler and make sure all the requests are working right.

Comment: What are the specifics of the CommunicationException? Please post the entire exception by catching it, displaying ex.ToString(), then using "throw;".

Comment: John, this is the CommunicationException Message:The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

I can't fit the full ToString() in a comment.

Comment: If I turn off "Just My Code" in the debugger, I can see this SerializationException at the WCF proxy as it receives the FaultException:
"Type 'System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal' with data contract name 'ArrayOfKeyValueOfanyTypeanyType:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arra..

Comment: This is pretty bizarre issue. Same thing happens to me and I am also using IErrorHandler with generic FaultExceptions. If I call the .exe directly I get my FaultException<T> on the client side just fine, try it with Visual Studio and I get a CommunicationException instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call this a fix/solution, but I have a workaround well suited to my situation.

As I said I had just started WCF Exception Handling, and I realised [IErrorHandler](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/implementing-ierrorhandler.aspx) is a better way to handle my exceptions, rather than method-level try/catch.

As the debugger jumps past the implementation of ProvideFault, the debugger doesn't look at the exception, and therefore it doesn't cause a CommunicationException.

This works for now, but I'd still like a real solution, as there may be cases where I want to provide specific exceptions, that will pass untouched through ProvideFault.